# How to solve simultaneous equations involving linear terms and trig functions?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

So I have the following set of equations which resulted from analysis of dynamic out-of-balance masses on two discs being balanced by masses in two separate planes. The set of equations are given by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
m_C & m_D & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & m_C & m_D \\
-m_C & m_D & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & m_C & -m_D
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos{\theta}_C \\
\cos{\theta}_D \\
\sin{\theta}_C \\
\sin{\theta}_D
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
A \\
B \\
C \\
D
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $A, B, C, D$ are known constants and ${\theta}_C, {\theta}_D, m_C, m_D$ are the unknowns to be solved for.

This is of course not a simple explicit linear set of equations in eg: $x, y, u, v$. Is there a way of solving this in MATLAB or a simple analytical solution for it or will I just need to go through it and solve by substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $$x_C = m_C \cos \theta_C$$   $$x_D = m_D \cos \theta_D$$ $$y_C = m_C \sin \theta_C$$   $$y_D = m_D \sin \theta_D$$

(basically, change from polar coordinates to cartesian coordinates) and you get a linear system.

Comment: Yes that works, thanks a lot!